# Application to check broken links

Tags: website, hyperlink

Is there a desktop or web applications that would search for broken links in my web site?

I want it to stay within the domain I give it and check links that go from one page to another as well as links that go to other websites. I'd like it to report 404, 5XX, 3XX and other errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Desktop link checkers**

- [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html). Free. Windows only.
- [DeepTrawl](http://www.deeptrawl.com/). Commercial. Windows & Mac.
- [InSpyder](http://www.inspyder.com/products/InSite/). Commercial. Windows only.
- [SortSite](http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/). Commercial. Windows only.
- [LinkScan](http://www.elsop.com/linkscan/). Commercial. Windows only.

**Web-based link checkers**

- [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink). Free. Checks entire site.
- [Broken Link Checker Tool - Dead Link Checker](https://www.deadlinkchecker.com/). Site Check: Free, Multi-checker: Free, Auto-Checker: Commercial.

Comment: there's a bunch I'd never heard of on that list - great resource :)

Answer (score 6):

[**LinkChecker**](http://linkchecker.sourceforge.net/) is a free, GPL licensed URL validator.

> recursive and multithreaded checking
>
> output in colored or normal text,
>   HTML, SQL, CSV, XML or a sitemap graph
>   in different formats
>
> HTTP/1.1, HTTPS, FTP, mailto:, news:,
>   nntp:, Telnet and local file links
>   support
>
> restriction of link checking with
>   regular expression filters for URLs
>
> proxy support
>
> username/password authorization for
>   HTTP and FTP and Telnet
>
> honors robots.txt exclusion protocol
>
> Cookie support
>
> HTML and CSS syntax check
>
> Antivirus check
>
> a command line interface
>
> a GUI client interface
>
> a (Fast)CGI web interface (requires
>   HTTP server)

Answer (score 5):

You can use W3C's link validation tool - [W3C's Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink).

Comment: good one     :)

Comment: geez Molly, must you answer the same things as I do? You always grab the upvotes!! :)

Comment: +1 as it checks recursively and is web-based too so you can run it without chewing up your own bandwidth in the process.

Comment: Very slow to use for more than one page as it checks links sequentially. Somethins like 'Link Sleuth' will check dozens of links at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I use the **[LinkChecker Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/532)** for checking single pages (the [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) is another, less friendly option).

For sets of pages or entire sites, the previously mentioned **[Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)** is very quick as (unlike the above options) it checks many links simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider running `wget` in `-spider` mode. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget for the `wget` man pages :)

`wget -spider <URL>` seems to be along the lines of what you're asking.