# Checking for dead links in a html file?

Tags: html, url, verification

I have a html file with several hundred links, a research database of mine, of a sort, collected over the years. What would be the easiest way to check which one of them are still alive ?

*(importing in firefox is out of the question)*

Comment: Dup of http://superuser.com/questions/38428/application-to-check-broken-links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [*wget*](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).  Simple, scriptable, command-line, and available on your favorite platform, whether it's Unix-ish, Win*, Cygwin, etc (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) for links to various versions).  From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

> `--spider`
>   When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.  For example, you can use Wget to check your bookmarks:
>
> `wget --spider --force-html -i bookmarks.html`
>
> This feature needs much more work for Wget to get close to the functionality of real web spiders.

You might want the `--no-verbose` and/or `--output-document=file` options too.

Comment: probably doable with *curl* too.

Comment: @quack why is the answer marked as CW ?

Comment: @sathya: why not? :)

Comment: That will do, yes. Btw, I don't think this should be CW.

Comment: @idigas: honestly, it's CW because i believe this question's a duplicate.  haven't managed to search up a predecessor yet tho.  no biggie; if someone wants to add a *curl* example they can.

Comment: @quack - interesting. I also thought that I saw this question before, but curiously, haven't been able to dig it up ...

Comment: @quack Hmm I see. Still, this answer warrants some rep love :-)